# Images not loading from folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a  php page called template.php and i have a logo  and when clicking on that it will change the logo image by selecting image file, am giving some manipulations in that page ,and sends data to my controller and then to model ,from there i am storing the data(the image)to my upload folder In code igniter framework.And then i redirect to the template.php page that i done all the manipulations ,The image is in the upload folders ,but when i am giving in the page uploads/image.png" is not working ,But after refreshing the page using ctrl+R Its getting the image replaced on the correct place in the logo  ,How to resolve this by loading  the image  without refreshing by pressing ctrl+R ?? since i have to get it work through javascript ??Is that php code not working or its not loading the image from resources ??

Comment: You'll have to use AJAX (If I understand your incoherent question)

Comment: <img alt="Logo" title="Logo" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/logo.png" style="width:100px;height:50px;margin-top:-10px;"> this is the image tag in the template.php file and the logo.png is still there in the database but its not changing in the page without refreshing this is what i done in model :   $image=$_FILES['strStudentPhoto']['name'];
    $type=$_FILES['strStudentPhoto']['type']; 
    $size=$_FILES['strStudentPhoto']['size'];
    $temp=$_FILES['strStudentPhoto']['tmp_name']; $move = move_uploaded_file($temp,'uploads/'. $image);

Comment: Then why should it works after pressing ctrl+R ???And then when clicking any other links also it works ,and after refreshing it works for several times !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use javascript and either preload all of the images, or use AJAX and call the image to be loaded.

This is because all php is executed on the server (server side script) and needs refreshing before it is sent to the browser. use a client side script (javascript) to execute it in the browser. AJAX can be a combination. the client side script calls a server side script and then gets the response

Comment: But after using ajax ,say using jquery if i replace the image tag with the current image i selected ,it will go after refreshing the page right ?? I want it there permanently

Comment: Now after giving a ajax to the submit button along with  submission it works ! I given the code to reloading the page  in the submit button ajax ,Is this code right ??